# Azure SQL Backup Restore

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql-managed-instance

How long will it take to restore 40GB full backup in Azure SQL database, Azure SQL Managed Instance?

Comment: As long as it takes. There are far too many factors that would affect such a process.

Comment: What's the top speed of my car?

Answer (score 0):

I have done a Point In Time Restore (PITR) on an over 500GB Azure SQL DB and it took around 8 hours total. This was not a managed instance, but hopefully that will give you a slight benchmark. Like the comment says, there are A LOT of factors that play into this, but it shouldn't take all day, but I also wouldn't expect it to take 10 minutes.